# Error - Invalid Form Key

Tags: magento-1.9, login, admin-panel, form-key

I meet a problem with magento 1.9.2.3, an error message appears when I connect with my custom admin form.

I created a module and I duplicated the **customer/account/login** page for my users role.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Page>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Custom_Page>
    </modules>
</config>
```

my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <Custom_Page>
                    <label>User Login</label>
                    <template>page/user_login.phtml</template>
                </Custom_Page>
            </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

No problem with old magento version.

But with 1.9.2.3: **The Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page** appears.

> **NOTE:** If I replace the old Observer.php it's done:

**www\app\code\core\Mage\Admin\Model\Observer.php**

But I think it's not serious to replace the new Observer.php with the old.

> **EDIT:** My user_login.phtml contains an input form_key.

```
<form action="/admin" method="post" id="login-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>"/>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which web browser did you use? Try using firefox because I was also getting this kind of error on Chrome.

Comment: I use Chrome but it's the same error with all web browser (Firefox, IE, Safari).

Comment: Can you please set "Cookie Domain" from system for making this thing correct.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem and could fix it by setting the correct

**web/cookie/cookie_domain**

and

**web/cookie/cookie_path**

values in the table `core_config_data`.

> Don't forget to clear all session and cookie data in your browser and
> the Magento session and cache files/data afterwards.

Comment: So, what do I have to set in this entries?

Comment: what are the entries please?

Answer (score 12):

I used these queries and could login again

`DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_path';`

and please make sure that webserver user has right to write to session storage.
checking `session_save_path` setting if you save session to files. It looks like this

`<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[/tmp/session]]></session_save_path>`

Comment: nice way without the need for phpmyadmin, thanks :)

Comment: Nice! This solution works for me!

Answer (score 5):

Newer versions of Magento require forms to have `<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />` to prevent CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) attacks.

Comment: Yes, I have already add an input form_key in my form and this is the same result.

Comment: Can you confirm that the form key is actually getting generated? (check the page source). This problem occurred when you upgraded Magento? From what version?

Comment: I'm sure, when I go to check the source page: ```<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="Pzty7ZxT6PWRSjhR"/>``` With magento 1.7.0.2 it's ok.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error after upgrading to **php7.0**. running magento **enterprise 1.9**.  I then tried every suggestion out there. Here is how I got it to work:

> 1. I added error reporting in my index.php, and fixed all the errors being reported.
> 2. In MySQL table `core_config_data`, I cleared values for `web/cookie_path web/cookie_httponly`.  Make sure you have the right
>      `web/cookie_domain` **value** with your domain (very important).
> 3. Clear your browser **cache** and **cookies**.

Answer (score 5):

Check your settings for https. If you use httpsfor your magento but trying open site with http you will have this a problem.

Comment: change config web/secure/use_in_adminhtml to 0 in that case

Comment: Thank you, @roman204, that was driving me crazy! I was so sure this setting just meant "use whatever is defined in secure base url" but apparently not, it tries to enforce https regardless. After almost a decade working with the blessed thing, I still hadn't encountered this quirk until now. Magento, the gift that just keeps giving :D :D

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error with Magento 1.9.2.3 after copying site on local web server on MAMP 3.

So, problem resolved when I changed in table `core_config_data` the `web/cookie/cookie_domain` to `mysite.lan` instead of the `mysite.lan:8888` .

Answer (score 2):

In my case I created the error with this steps:
I had moved a magento copy (dev) in the magento itself:
**magento/magento-copy**
Before, they where next to each other on the server. Everyone with his own quota.
So moving one qutoa into the other -> problems occured.
Cause I could not view the magento-copy with FTP I changed the owner of the files by file-editor. For any reason this created the error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this was working on Linux but on my local windows environment using virtualbox/Docker and windows 10 this error was caused by the weird permissions that vb/docker/windows gives to /var/sessions/.  On my local development environment only I moved the path from a mapped windows drive to a "real" path on the linux VM

I added this to the config file `app/etc/local.xml`, then deleted all files in `var/cache` and `var/session` and could login OK.

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
<session_save_path><![CDATA[/tmp]]></session_save_path>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can login on https://yourwebsite/admin instead http
and check core_config_data web/secure/use_in_adminhtml

i've got similar problem and login works only on secure

Answer (score 1):

I often get this problem when I am working on several development sites and live sites, and there is some cookie confusion. Previously I've fixed it with MySQL queries and deleting files but I have found a neater way to solve the problem.

The magerun tool provides a way to check for problems with the cookie path and to fixe them. magerun isn't a part of Magento, so you will need to install it. It is described as a swiss-army-knife for magento, so you could find it useful for other things.

To download it:

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun.phar
```

Then

```
chmod +x n98-magerun.phar
```

Then check the cookie path for problems...

```
./n98-magerun.phar config:get web/cookie/*
```

It will print a table. Look at the value for `web/cookie/cookie_domain`. When I am having this problem it does not match the proper hostname for the site (e.g. I get `dev.example.com` instead of `www.example.com`).

To fix it you need to reset the path and flush the cache, which magerun can help with...

```
./n98-magerun.phar config:set web/cookie/cookie_domain ""
./n98-magerun.phar cache:flush
```

You should then be able to log in again.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the accepted answer ( https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/102678/6078 ) the correct entries are

#### web/cookie/cookie_domain = your base url like:

```
https://website.com/ (without any store code)
```

**and**

#### web/cookie/cookie_path

typically just `/` but can be `/[storecode]/` also per store

For local development it usually works to delete `cookie_domain` or leave it empty but it seems like Microsoft Edge 80 has issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was php version 7.2 .

change my php version for 5.6 in .htaccess

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php56/lib

Answer (score 0):

Another way this error can happen for homemade admin modules is when `frontName` in your `routes.xml` doesn't match the `<add action"someFrontName/someAction" />` in your `menu.xml`. This causes the key you see in the link when trying to open the module to be different than expected.

Answer (score 0):

After copying your magento 1 site to a new domain, Varien.php may still have the old domain name in the file.

To ensure your admin form is using the new 'cookie domain, update any references to your old domain in the Varien.php file located in your site at:

```
/<magento_html_dir>/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
```

After making the edits, run a cache flush/clean, and reindex all (n98-magerun tool is good for this): Example:

```
n98-magerun cache:clean
n98-magerun cache:flush
n98-magerun index:reindex:all
```