# Error - Invalid Form Key on Admin Login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, admin-login

I set up a development environment for a magento instance. I cloned it to my local server, changed the URLs in Database, cleared cache and deleted old sessions.

If I want to login or reset my password, I always get this message:

```
 "Ungültiger Form Key. Bitte aktualisieren Sie die Seite."
 "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the current Page."
```

I already checked other answers. I tried to set **`cookie_domain`** and **`cookie_path`** to empty value & also disabled the **`use_form_key`** with setting it to **0**. Cleared cache, checked permissions etc.

Every time I get this error.

Any ideas what I could do more?

Comment: have you refreshed your page?

Comment: yes, of course i refreshed the page.

Comment: have you removed browser cache?

Comment: Yes, cleared Browser cache, removed all Cookies, tried different Browsers

Comment: Is any form_key submitted at all? Check the corresponding request inside your browser's dev tools for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error - Invalid Form Key](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99407/error-invalid-form-key)

Comment: @pong: yes, the form key is submitted.

Comment: i currently have use_form_key disabled. why it always wants to check it?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara nope, already tried.

Comment: Do you have a staging site with similar domain? I ran into this and had to update my cookie settings to the exact domain `www.domain.com` and `staging.domain.com` - then cleared cookies from my browser and am able to login to both without this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Opened a new Chrome Browser on Anonymous, and voi la, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was just running into this issue. After searching around a while I just had a look to `var/log/system.log`. In my case I got:

`Warning: session_start(): open(path/var/session/sess_8ba6b13f0d6426e823c9a85e27a619de, O_RDWR) failed: Disk quota exceeded (122)  in /path/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 133`

So the webspcae was just not enough to store another session file. I deleted some backup files from webspace, did a reload of the login-page and everthing was ok again. Maybe this helps someone..

Comment: `Disk quota exceeded (122)` can also mean that the **number of files** is too much. In my case I was deleted nearly all big files on the server and finally found out that just the number of files was exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked by enabling logs from **System -> Configuration -> Advanced (Developer) -> Log Settings**?

One more thing you could do is to add **error reporting** in **index.php** file in Magento root. If this is PHP error, you will be able to get some clue from that.

Please let me know if you find above solution working.