# Magento Login Redirection Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, redirect

I am using Magento ver. 1.9.3.2. The issue is customer login page not redirecting to account page.

**Login.phtm code**

```
<div class="account-login">
    <div class="page-title">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Login or Create an Account') ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 new-users">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Customers') ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more.') ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?>" class="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo Mage::helper('persistent')->getCreateAccountUrl($this->getCreateAccountUrl()) ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 registered-users">
                <div class="content">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Registered Customers') ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('If you have an account with us, please log in.') ?></p>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
                        <li>
                            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="pass" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
                    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>
                    <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('checkout')->isContextCheckout()): ?>
            <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

**Cookie settings**
[image]

Please help I have tried cleaning cache multiple times, please help I am just redirected to the login page. There is no error message.

Comment: no error message mean  form_key is invalid . You nee fix  the form  key_issue

Comment: and how?? please explain

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99407/error-invalid-form-key

Comment: Can you please copy solution here?

Comment: Is this a redirection issue or you not able to set cookie/session?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin > System > Configuration > Customer Configuration, under the Login Options set `Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in` to **Yes**, Save and refresh your cache.

**UPDATE:**

If it doesn't work for you, you can create un observer for this, `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_loginPost`

```
public function redirectCustomer($observer){
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl().'acustomer/account';
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: that is yes already

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for you, look my update.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the redirection issue or you not able to set login session?

If the redirection issue then follow steps as @pЯincƏ suggesting.

Else proper cookie is not set.

Set `cookie Path` to `/`

set `cookie domain` to `.example.com`

Rest is OK.